# for each loop in trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

Unable to use for each loop in trigger
I am getting

> Error Code: 1064

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE
    TRIGGER `TRG_AU_DEVICES_HOWLONG` AFTER UPDATE ON `devices` 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
     DECLARE lastid INTEGER;
     DECLARE a, b, c VARCHAR(255);
    SET @lastid := (SELECT deviceId FROM devices ORDER BY packetDate DESC LIMIT 1);
    DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT alertType,deviceId FROM alerts WHERE alerts.deviceId = @lastid ;
        OPEN cur1;
        read_loop: LOOP
        FETCH cur1 INTO a, b;
      insert into test(alertType,deviceId) values(a,b);
    END LOOP;
CLOSE cur1;
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Unable to use for each loop in trigger, am getting  `Error Code: 1064`.How to use for each loop in trigger

Comment: ALL declare statement must appear immediately after the begin statement. You should also read the manual particularly about the use of handlers with cursors.

Comment: Within the trigger body, the OLD and NEW keywords enable you to access columns in the rows affected by a trigger. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html

Answer (score 0):

DELIMITER $$

CREATE
   TRIGGER `TRG_TEST` BEFORE UPDATE ON `devices` 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE alert VARCHAR(255);

DECLARE my_cur CURSOR FOR SELECT alertType FROM alerts WHERE deviceId =  8170610948;
   DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;
         OPEN my_cur;
    my_cur_loop:
    LOOP FETCH my_cur INTO a;
        IF done = 1 THEN
            LEAVE my_cur_loop;
        END IF;
        INSERT INTO test (alertType)VALUES(alert);
    END LOOP my_cur_loop;
CLOSE my_cur;

END;
$$

Comment: var selcol = $('.test');
$(selcol).each(function(i, elm) {
                        console.log($(this));
                        console.log($(this).trigger('click'));
                    });

I tried this and have 3 columns and 3 columns have the same class when I run drag and drop that time tigger calls in only 2 times not 3 times.

$(".tree_view_row").find("table").find("tbody").sortable({
/// here code
});

Comment: I got solution because of sortable default functionality, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing your own *looped array* inside the **array**. I call this a loop bomb.

Since you expect the statement inside the loop to return control to the loop, but the flow of logic can not reversed halfway through a loop mechanically.It can be conditioned, not reversed because the array is not expressed, it is defined.

To Achieve logical expression of the array before the construct, consider using, predefined data matrices, lambda functions or Using Lambda programming that includes meta or reflective paradigms. Lisp, GUILE, OCAMEL are examples.